# C : Converting all special char to the equivalent (é => e)

Tags: c, function, ascii

I need to code a Caesar cipher in C, so I'm working step by step to understand everything I'm doing.

I need to take care of special chars
example : if a user enters

"This is a déjà vù !" 
it will convert this to 
 "This is a deja vu"

**Is there a C function capable of doing this instead of doing it by hand for each special char in  ASCII code ?**

This is what I'm trying to avoid :

```
case -85 :
case -86 :
case -87 :
case -88 :
    *p = 'e';
```

Comment: And what would you want 人 to convert to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a C function capable of doing this instead of doing it by hand for each special char in ASCII code ?

[Iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) will do what you want when you choose `ASCII//TRANSLIT` as the target encoding.

Comment: oh thanks i didn't know it was a function in C too :O http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html

Comment: btw, if you have a simple example in C, because each example i find has 40 lines of incomprehensible code for a C beginner. Thanks :)

Comment: @Tristan: From a quick look at the docs, I believe the short version is `cd = iconv_open(tocode, fromcode);` (probably codes for UTF-8 and ASCII in your case), followed by `iconv(cd, inbuf, inbufsize, outbuf, outbufsize);` (the buffers and sizes should be the addresses of copies of your input, since they are changed by iconv), then check for errors, and finally `iconv_close(cd);`. `cd` can be reused as many times as you want; you can open it at startup and close at shutdown.

Comment: @jefromi I'm currently trying that :http://pastie.org/private/ss43mrii1ss2wseygjsiww . Could you tell me how to replace outbuf / outbufsize please ?

Comment: @Tristan: you didn't paste in the declarations of any of your variables. However, `argv[1]` and `strlen(argv[1])` should be replaced with addresses of copies. (e.g. `char *argv1 = argv[1]; ... iconv(..., &argv1, ...);`.) `iconv` modifies its arguments, so that afterward if something failed, you can check to see if you ran unexpectedly ran out of room in a buffer, and see the partial result, and so on.

Comment: @Tristan: I'm not really sure about how much of a C beginner you are - but if you need help getting this to work, I'd suggest simply posting another question asking directly how to do it, not just what function you'd use.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 'equivalent' depends on your culture.
Is ü (u-umlaut) equivalent to u or 'oe' ?

Comment: it's equivalent to "u" to me :'). Do you have any example of the use of iconv in C btw ? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry never heard of iconv before - just saying the reason it isn't a standard function is that there is no way to do it unless you know what language/locale settings.